# Writing to registry on Windows 7 64-bit by means of JNIWrapper - Performance issue

Tags: registry, windows-7-x64, jniwrapper

Our installation uses `jniwrapper` library. 
Now, we started installing on Windows 7 64-bit machines and are facing a problem.

To write values to registry we use the function
`com.jniwrapper.win32.registry.RegistryKeyValues.put()`

As long as we install in the context of the *system administrator user*, and of course with elevation, the installation works fine.
But when we log in as *another administrative user*, elevate his privileges, and start the installation then it takes much more time. Nearer analysis showed us that now the above `jniwrapper` function needs about 15 seconds time for every single registry write operation!

Do you know how to solve the problem on 64-bit version of Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

`com.jniwrapper.win32.registry.RegistryKeyValues.put()` is not an install4j function. The install4j API to write to registry entries is available from `com.install4j.api.windows.WinRegistry`, see

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/windows/WinRegistry.html

Comment: I have to correct myself: we use the above JNIWrapper put() function to write to registry. This function causes our problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only help you with the install4j API